# Wordpress: Static pages, but one page with posts and one with contact form

Tags: forms, wordpress, static, contacts, posts

I have set up a fresh custom template from the scratch for wordpress with only six static pages.

Now, I have two questions/problems:

1. How do I put up posts (without comments) on **one** of those pages? The aim is, that five pages are just giving out static content, but only **one** of those pages should be showing posts like a little diary/blog within an otherwise static website. Right now with the given code (see below) all six pages give out just the static content from "pages" within Wordpress, which is okay, but I just can not figure out, how to put the posts on one single pages of those six.
2. How can I add a conctact form on one of those static pages? I mean, they are all getting the same input over my index.php or pages.php, but where do I set the PHP code for the contact form and how do I insert it to just one of those pages (for example CONTACT)?

Here is my code up to now:

index.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>  
<?php the_content(); ?>  
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

page.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?> 

<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();?>  
<?php the_content(); ?>  
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thank you in advance.

---

**To clear things up**:

**Problem 1**:

I have a static website in wordpress with six pages (see www.studio-scs.de, if that helps) and those six pages load the content of the pages throughout page.php, of course.

My problem is now, I need ONE of those six pages (for example TERMINE) to show POSTS, while the other six are still showing NO POSTS, but the PAGE content.

But how can I do that, if all links/pages refer to **page.php**, which has the code to just state PAGE content without POSTS (see above)?

**Problem 2**:

On one of the other five pages I want to add a contact form, which needs some PHP code in the header, of course.

But how and where do I insert that, if all pages are loaded by page.php with the same code? Do I have to enter that into header.php and just leave it there loaded all the time/pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your **First problem** create a new Template and put POST function there and add that template in Dashboard-->pages--> right hand side-->Template and choose template from drop down.[image]

e ius

For Problem 2

Add your PHP code to HEADER.php once, that call each time and display only specific page, where it requried.

Comment: Alright, problem 2 is understood/solved, but what do you mean with create a new template in problem 1? Do you mean a theme? Create a complete new theme? But how is that helping? There are installed twentyten and twentyeleven, already, but I could not find them in creating a new page, also I had no drop-down-menu for "template". Or are you talking about creating a new file like "termine.php". Do I have to give that some code, that it is be seen as a "template"?

Comment: <?php /* Template Name:abc */ ?>  this is code for template and save it with any name and place your code. And this will appear in Dashboard>>pages>>add new>>right hand side an a DROP DOWN with title of Templates, choose this template and SAVE that page, and DONE!!!

Answer (score 2):

Excaly i am not getting your point, how ever i think you want to add post and contact form7 on same page.

Then use this code.

```
<?php /* Template Name:ABC*/ ?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
global $post;
$args = array( 'numberposts' => LIMIT OF POST, 'category' => CATEGORY ID );


$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :
setup_postdata($post); ?>

<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_content(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

<!--Contact Form Start Here-->

<?php echo do_shortcode('[CONTACT FORM SHOT CODE HERE]'); ?>

<!--Contact Form END Here-->

<?php get_sidebar();

get_footer();

?>
```

Comment: I added some more info at the end of my question. Maybe that clears things up? It is not about posts and contact form in one page, but about two different problems. :)